# I can't delete an item from a drop-down menu properly. It deletes more than one

Tags: javascript, html

The HTML create two drop-down menu and one delete button. One JavaScript, I made a code to fill those drop-down box with arrays. And, every time I change the item on the first drop-down menu, a new set of options appears on the second drop-down menu. The goal is, whenever I clicked the delete button, I should be able to delete an item on the second drop-down and when I changed the item on the first drop-down menu, hence another set of option will appear on the second drop-down menu, I should be able to delete an item from there as well.

The problem is, once the set of items on the second drop-down menu has been changed, a bunch of unwanted results occurs, such as deleting more than one items or deleting on another set of items. **For example**, if I delete something from "meal", it'll delete one item. Then if I go over to "dessert" and delete something from there, it'll delete one item. But if I go back to "meal" again, a bunch of items are now deleted. Just try it out yourself to see what I mean

```js
let mealListArr = ["Steak", "Pasta", "Sushi", "Burger"];
let dessertListArr = ["Ice Cream", "Cake", "Chocolate", "Candy"];
let breadListArr = ["French Bread", "White Bread", "Sour Bread", "Cookies"];
let drinkListArr = ["Coke", "Water", "Mango Shake", "Orange Juice"];

// Transfer Array to First Drop Down Menu
let menuType = document.getElementById("menu-type");
let menuTypeArr = ["Meal", "Dessert", "Bread", "Drink"];

fillDropDown(menuTypeArr, menuType);

// Transfer Array to Second Drop Down Menu
let menuList = document.getElementById("menu-list");

fillDropDown(mealListArr, menuList);

// Change List on second drop-down based on first drop-down
menuType.addEventListener("change", function () {
  var menuOption = menuType.options[menuType.selectedIndex].text;
  for (let i = 0; i < menuList.length; ) {
    menuList.remove(0);
  }

  if (menuOption == "Meal") {
    fillDropDown(mealListArr, menuList);
  } else if (menuOption == "Dessert") {
    fillDropDown(dessertListArr, menuList);
  } else if (menuOption == "Bread") {
    fillDropDown(breadListArr, menuList);
  } else if (menuOption == "Drink") {
    fillDropDown(drinkListArr, menuList);
  }
});

function fillDropDown(arr, dropDown) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let opt = arr[i];
    let el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    dropDown.appendChild(el);
  }
  return arr, dropDown;
}

// Delete Item on second drop-down
let delMenuBtn = document.getElementById("menu-btn-trash");
menuOption = menuType.options[menuType.selectedIndex].text;
subMenuOption = menuList.options[menuList.selectedIndex].text;
  
delMenuBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    menuList.remove(menuList.selectedIndex);
    if (menuOption == "Meal") {
      mealListArr.splice(mealListArr.indexOf(subMenuOption), 1);
    } else if (menuOption == "Dessert") {
      dessertListArr.splice(dessertListArr.indexOf(subMenuOption), 1);
    } else if (menuOption == "Bread") {
      breadListArr.splice(breadListArr.indexOf(subMenuOption), 1);
    } else if (menuOption == "Drink") {
      drinkListArr.splice(drinkListArr.indexOf(subMenuOption), 1);
    }
});
```

```html
<select id="menu-type"></select>
<select id="menu-list"></select>
<button id="menu-btn-trash">Delete</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What were you doing wrong?**
In practice your code stored in the variable `menuOption` the first menu, doing so every time you tried to delete something it was removed from the first menu

**Solution**

1. Call up the menu variable as often as needed
2. Store index before remove it
3. Extra:

   - Use `menuList.selectedIndex` instead of `drinkListArr.indexOf(subMenuOption)`
   - Use `menuType.value` instead of `menuType.options[menuType.selectedIndex].text`

```js
let mealListArr = ["Steak", "Pasta", "Sushi", "Burger"];
let dessertListArr = ["Ice Cream", "Cake", "Chocolate", "Candy"];
let breadListArr = ["French Bread", "White Bread", "Sour Bread", "Cookies"];
let drinkListArr = ["Coke", "Water", "Mango Shake", "Orange Juice"];

// Transfer Array to First Drop Down Menu
let menuType = document.getElementById("menu-type");
let menuTypeArr = ["Meal", "Dessert", "Bread", "Drink"];

fillDropDown(menuTypeArr, menuType);

// Transfer Array to Second Drop Down Menu
let menuList = document.getElementById("menu-list");

fillDropDown(mealListArr, menuList);

// Change List on second drop-down based on first drop-down
menuType.addEventListener("change", function () {  
  let menuOption = menuType.value;
  for (let i = 0; i < menuList.length; ) {
    menuList.remove(0);
  }

  if (menuOption == "Meal") {
    fillDropDown(mealListArr, menuList);
  } else if (menuOption == "Dessert") {
    fillDropDown(dessertListArr, menuList);
  } else if (menuOption == "Bread") {
    fillDropDown(breadListArr, menuList);
  } else if (menuOption == "Drink") {
    fillDropDown(drinkListArr, menuList);
  }
});

function fillDropDown(arr, dropDown) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let opt = arr[i];
    let el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    dropDown.appendChild(el);
  }
  return arr, dropDown;
}

// Delete Item on second drop-down
let delMenuBtn = document.getElementById("menu-btn-trash");
  
delMenuBtn.addEventListener("click", function () { 
   let index = menuList.selectedIndex;
    let menuOption = menuType.value;
    menuList.remove(menuList.selectedIndex);
   console.log(menuOption);
    if (menuOption == "Meal") {
      mealListArr.splice(index, 1);
    } else if (menuOption == "Dessert") {
      dessertListArr.splice(index, 1);
    } else if (menuOption == "Bread") {
      breadListArr.splice(index, 1);
    } else if (menuOption == "Drink") {
      drinkListArr.splice(index, 1);
    }
});
```

```html
<select id="menu-type"></select>
<select id="menu-list"></select>
<button id="menu-btn-trash">Delete</button>
```